# I'm trying to search an ArrayList of objects for duplicates and if it doesnt exist add the new object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Class called Subject which will store some information like a subject name and a subject code, I'm struggling because what I'm trying to do is make it loop through the list of records in the arraylist and add the new record if it doesn't already exist. Please help, Ive tried searching for an answer on here but haven't seem to be able to find it.

If looping is not the right thing to do please point me in the right direction.
Thanks

```
//The Class

public class Subject {
    private String name;
    private String subjectCode;

    public Subject(){    
    }

    public Subject(String name, String subjectCode){
        this.name = name;
        this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubjectCode(){
        return this.subjectCode;
    }

public void setSubjectCode(String subjectCode){
    this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
}


//The Main method

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Test records
    subjectList.add(new Subject("Java 1", "ITC101"));
    subjectList.add(new Subject("Java 2", "ITC201"));
    subjectList.add(new Subject("Java 3", "ITC301"));


    String newGetName;
    String newSubjectCode;


    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Subject Name: ");
        newGetName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Subject Code: ");
        newSubjectCode = input.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < subjectList.size(); i++){
            if(!subjectList.get(i).getName().contains(newGetName) && !subjectList.get(i).getSubjectCode().contains(newSubjectCode)){
            subjectList.add(new Subject(newGetName, newSubjectCode));
            } else {
                    System.out.println("We have a match ");

            }
        }
    } while(!"0".equals(newGetName));


}
```

Comment: If you need a container with no duplicates, consider using a `Set` instead.

Comment: You need to iterate the entire `subjectList` to check if already contains `newGetName` (as is, you're adding it multiple times when the current `subject` doesn't match). Consider overriding equals in `subject` and using a `Set`.

Comment: Your class should provide an appropriate equals method for comparing.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a "no match" too soon: you need to walk the whole list before adding a new subject.

Your program tries the first subject, and if ut does not match, it adds a subject, and moves on. Unfortunately, it does not break, so it keeps adding the same subject for each existing one that does not match.

In order to fix this problem make a boolean variable called "found", set it to false before the loop, and search for matches. Once a match is found, set the variable to true, and break.

After the loop check your variable. If it's true, do not add, and say that you found a duplicate. Otherwise, add the new subject.

Answer (score -1):

in your case, you can not check for 'contains' you have to manually check every entry if its the same.

override the equal() function of your Subject:

```
public boolean equal(Object o){
   Subject b = (Subject) o;
   return (this.name.equal(b.name) && this.code.equal(b.code));
}
```

then in your loop:

```
boolean found = false;
for(Subject s : subjectList){
   if(s.equal(newSubject)){
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}
if(!found) //add new entry
```

Comment: If you require the creation of the `Subject` instance to search for it by implementing `equals()`, you might as well use the [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method of the list to do the search.

Comment: you are right, contains use equal to ... why the down vote? i think, it is what the TO wanted?

Answer (score -1):

If `Subject` implements `equals()`, then create the object and call `subjectList.contains(subject)`. Better yet, implement `hashCode()` too and change the `ArrayList` to a `HashSet` (or `LinkedHashSet` if order is important) for better performance.

Otherwise, search like this (using `equals()`, not `contains()`, for string comparison):

```
boolean found = false;
for (Subject subject : subjectList)
    if (subject.getName().equals(newGetName) && subject.getSubjectCode().equals(newSubjectCode)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
if (found)
    System.out.println("We have a match ");
else
    subjectList.add(new Subject(newGetName, newSubjectCode));
```